# How to set up a p-value based significance testing (example experiment is given)

Tags: p-value

I am a software engineer performing a real-life A/B test, and I wanted to use conventional statistical tools to make sure my results were statistically significant. I have some basic textbook knowledge of p-values but have rarely used them in real world applications.

Let's say I have two different blackbox methods of creating a cookie, namely Method A and Method B. Both methods produce cookies at a rate of 1 cookie / 1 second. In both methods, the baked cookie can be either Acceptable quality or Defective quality.

I let Method A and Method B running for 1 week.

For Method A, out of 25200 cookies, 10000 were Acceptable, which means the success ratio for this method is 10000/25200 = 39.68%.

For Method B, out of 25200 cookies, 9000 were Acceptable, which would yield success ratio of 9000/25200=35.71%.

It seems like Method A is better than Method B by a whooping 3.97%, but before I rush to conclusions, how would I compute my p-value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several versions of this test, essentially using
a normal approximation. Some use a continuity correction
(declined below on account of large sample sizes), and
some use a pooled standard error for the difference in
the two estimates of proportions (others find standard errors
separately). The version implemented in R (shown below)
is equivalent to doing a chi-squared test on a $2 \times 2$
table of successes and failures for the two methods.

For your suggested data the P-value of the two-sided test
is $0.029,$ so you could claim significance at level $2\%.$

```
prop.test(c(1000,900), c(25200, 25200), cor=F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(1000, 900) out of c(25200, 25200)
X-squared = 5.4693, df = 1, p-value = 0.01935
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.0006427583 0.0072937496
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.03968254 0.03571429
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two proportions. A basic test of difference between two proportions should work.

https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/hypothesis-testing/z-test/